# Scheme allow uppercase define

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

To define a `square` in scheme I can do the following:

```
(define (square x) (* x x)
```

However, if I use a capital `DEFINE`, I get an invalid identifier:

```
(DEFINE (square x) (* x x)
```

Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
#lang sicp
; using DrRacket
(define (DEFINE) define) ; sort of a macro where DEFINE expands to define
```

Comment: Since `DEFINE` is syntax, you can't define it with `define`. You need to define it as a macro.

Comment: @Barmar right, how would that be done, using a macro?

Comment: Read about [`define-syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._define-syntax%29%29)

Comment: Another thing you could do is wrap `#ci(begin ...)` around the entire body of your module. The `#ci` prefix switches Racket's reader to case-insensitive mode (which really means that it downcases any symbols that it reads) for the next S-expression.

Comment: @RyanCulpepper oh that's perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a macro to create syntax that uses the `define` syntax, and the macro needs to be able to take arguments in all of the ways that `define` can.

For R6RS Scheme, [R6RS says](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.2):

```
(define <variable> <expression>)‌‌           syntax 
(define <variable>)‌‌                        syntax 
(define (<variable> <formals>) <body>)‌‌     syntax 
(define (<variable> . <formal>) <body>)‌‌    syntax
```

Since the R6RS Scheme `define` syntax requires at least one argument, this macro requires at least one argument, and it will allow all of the above uses. Note that the pattern `(_ e1 e2 ...)` matches `_` with `DEFINE`, and then *one* or more expressions:

```
(define-syntax DEFINE
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ e1 e2 ...)
     (define e1 e2 ...))))
```

Racket's `define` syntax requires at least *two* arguments, and this is also true of `define` in R5RS and R7RS Scheme. The `sicp` language follows R5RS, so the `define` in `#lang sicp` should also require two arguments. Racket has a convenient `define-syntax-rule` form that is more concise than `define-syntax`, though either would work here. Note that the pattern `(DEFINE e1 e2 e3 ...)` matches `DEFINE` and then *two* or more expressions:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax-rule (DEFINE e1 e2 e3 ...) (define e1 e2 e3 ...))
```

But, the `sicp` language does not have `define-syntax-rule`, so we will have to settle for `define-syntax`, with pattern matching as in R5RS:

```
#lang sicp

(define-syntax DEFINE
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ e1 e2 e3 ...)
     (define e1 e2 e3 ...))))
```

Some example uses of the final `#lang sicp` definition:

```
> (DEFINE x 42)
> x
42
> (DEFINE (my-add x y) (+ x y))
> (my-add 1 2)
3
> (DEFINE (my-list . xs) xs)
> (my-list 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
> (DEFINE (my-args a b . c) (cons (list a b) c))
> (my-args 1 2 3 4 5)
((1 2) 3 4 5)
```

The first of these two would be legal in R6RS Scheme, but not in R5RS or R7RS Scheme, `#lang racket`, or `#lang sicp`:

```
> (DEFINE x)
; define-uppercase.rkt:56:0: DEFINE: bad syntax
;   in: {DEFINE x}
> (DEFINE)
; define-uppercase.rkt:57:0: DEFINE: bad syntax
;   in: {DEFINE}
```